# Value is NaN when I submit

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to submit value from 2 numbers.

I have a quantity and default_price

In html I write

```
 <div *ngIf="addForm.controls.producut_id.value === '22'">
        <input readonly formControlName="p_Subtotal" type="text" [value]='producte.default_price*p_Quantity'>
 </div>
```

Problem is that, when I submit value, value save `NaN`, not real value.

Can you ask me any idea please?

Comment: I would guess that one of either `producte.default_price` or `p_Quantity` is undefined, double check that they are set to the values you're expecting

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) please .

Comment: Nobody can tell what exactly your problem, the problems clearly is from data that we don't know about, and your line of code missing a lot of important parts, like where `producte` came from and `p_Quantity` and so on, you need to provide full example, also it maybe your misspelling is the reason, it is `product` maybe not `producte`?

Comment: Your variable names use two different misspellings for the word "product", the real variable name could be anything...

Comment: @Arash please look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8zwvg?file=app/app.component.ts thank you

Comment: Are you should that you want to edit total field ? this field should be in span or some none editable element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" [value]="price*quantity" class="validate">
```

you should write

```
  <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" [value]="myform.value.price * myform.value.quantity" class="validate">
```

As well as your elements are keeping in you'r form variable which is myform.value .

Note. But I still suggest you to show total field to user in a none editable html field Eg   and etc.

So if you want to accept my suggestion , you should write like below

```
<span>{{myform.value.price * myform.value.quantity}}</span>
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but please look in console, total is empty https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mno3gk?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: First you have an error in you'r console and its because in you'r hello.component.ts you should declare products like :   products: Array<Products> = [];

Comment: test whether you get result after fix above error ?

Comment: What do you mean by you cant get any value ? I don't understand

Comment: `{description: "fdsf",id: "1",name: "gdf",price: "3",quantity: "33",total: ""}`

Comment: Total: EMPTY, I want to submit value, 99

Comment: I got it, will come back soon

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ygfd5?file=app/hello.component.ts